# Android: Animation works in KitKat and LolliPop but not on other API versions

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, expandablelistview

I have to build animation like [This](https://db.tt/1RXK8vzM). 
Sorry I don't have too much reputation to upload image. you can find gif file from the above link.
 I have done all this and it works fine on KitKat and LollyPop only but not on the other API version. I am using [this](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView) library. Can any one please figure out the actual problem
Here is my code. Thanks in advance

```
public abstract class AbstractSlideExpandableListAdapter extends WrapperListAdapterImpl
```

{

```
private View lastOpnUpperView = null;
ArrayList<View> upperViewsList = new ArrayList<View>();
ArrayList<View> lowerViewsList = new ArrayList<View>();
ArrayList<View> circleViewsList = new ArrayList<View>();


private View lastOpen = null;

private int lastOpenPosition = -1;

private int lastOpenItemIndex = 0;

private int animationDuration = 800;


private BitSet openItems = new BitSet();


private final SparseIntArray viewHeights = new SparseIntArray(10);


private ViewGroup parent;

public AbstractSlideExpandableListAdapter(ListAdapter wrapped)
{
    super(wrapped);
    lastOpenPosition = 0;
    openItems.set(lastOpenPosition, true);
}

private OnItemExpandCollapseListener expandCollapseListener;


public void setItemExpandCollapseListener(OnItemExpandCollapseListener listener)
{
    expandCollapseListener = listener;
}

public void removeItemExpandCollapseListener()
{
    expandCollapseListener = null;
}


public interface OnItemExpandCollapseListener
{

    public void onExpand(View itemView, int position);


    public void onCollapse(View itemView, int position);

}

private void notifiyExpandCollapseListener(int type, View view, int position)
{
    if (expandCollapseListener != null)
    {
        if (type == ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND)
        {
            expandCollapseListener.onExpand(view, position);
        }
        else if (type == ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE)
        {
            expandCollapseListener.onCollapse(view, position);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    this.parent = viewGroup;
    view = wrapped.getView(position, view, viewGroup);

    enableFor(view, position);

    return view;
}


public abstract View getExpandToggleButton(View parent);

public abstract View getExpandableView(View parent);

// upperView to expand animation for sequeeze
public abstract View getUpperView(View upperView);

// Lower view to expand and collapse
public abstract View getLowerView(View upperView);

// Get the circle view to hide and show
public abstract View getCircleView(View circleView);

/**
 * Gets the duration of the collapse animation in ms. Default is 330ms. Override this method to change the default.
 * 
 * @return the duration of the anim in ms
 */
public int getAnimationDuration()
{
    return animationDuration;
}

/**
 * Set's the Animation duration for the Expandable animation
 * 
 * @param duration
 *            The duration as an integer in MS (duration > 0)
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException
 *                if parameter is less than zero
 */
public void setAnimationDuration(int duration)
{
    if (duration < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration is less than zero");
    }

    animationDuration = duration;
}

/**
 * Check's if any position is currently Expanded To collapse the open item @see collapseLastOpen
 * 
 * @return boolean True if there is currently an item expanded, otherwise false
 */
public boolean isAnyItemExpanded()
{
    return (lastOpenPosition != -1) ? true : false;
}

public void enableFor(View parent, int position)
{
    View more = getExpandToggleButton(parent);
    View itemToolbar = getExpandableView(parent);
    View upperView = getUpperView(parent);
    View circleView = getCircleView(parent);
    View lowerView = getLowerView(parent);
    itemToolbar.measure(parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight());

    upperViewsList.add(upperView);
    circleViewsList.add(circleView);
    lowerViewsList.add(lowerView);

    if (position == 0)
    {
        // lastopenUpperViewTemporary = upperView;
        lastOpnUpperView = upperView;
        upperView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lowerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    enableFor(more, upperView, itemToolbar, position);
    itemToolbar.requestLayout();
}

private void animateListExpand(final View button, final View target, final int position)
{

    target.setAnimation(null);

    int type;
    if (target.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        type = ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE;
    }
    else
    {
        type = ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND;
    }
    // remember the state
    if (type == ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND)
    {
        openItems.set(position, true);
    }
    else
    {
        openItems.set(position, false);
    }

    // check if we need to collapse a different view
    if (type == ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND)
    {
        if (lastOpenPosition != -1 && lastOpenPosition != position)
        {
            if (lastOpen != null)
            {
                animateWithUpperView(lastOpen, ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE, position);
                // animateView(lastOpen, ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE);
                notifiyExpandCollapseListener(ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE, lastOpen, lastOpenPosition);
            }
            openItems.set(lastOpenPosition, false);
        }

        lastOpen = target;
        lastOpenPosition = position;
    }
    else if (lastOpenPosition == position)
    {
        lastOpenPosition = -1;
    }
    // animateView(target, type);
    // Expand the view which was collapse
    Animation anim = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(target, type);
    anim.setDuration(getAnimationDuration());
    target.startAnimation(anim);

    this.notifiyExpandCollapseListener(type, target, position);
    // }
}

private void enableFor(final View button, final View upperView, final View target, final int position)
{
    // lastopenUpperViewTemporary = upperView;
    if (target == lastOpen && position != lastOpenPosition)
    {
        // lastOpen is recycled, so its reference is false
        lastOpen = null;
    }
    if (position == lastOpenPosition)
    {
        // re reference to the last view
        // so when can animate it when collapsed
        // lastOpen = target;
        lastOpen = target;
        lastOpnUpperView = upperView;
    }
    int height = viewHeights.get(position, -1);
    if (height == -1)
    {
        viewHeights.put(position, target.getMeasuredHeight());
        updateExpandable(target, position);
    }
    else
    {
        updateExpandable(target, position);
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view)
        {

            System.out.println("Position: " + position);
            if (lastOpenPosition == position)
            {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Upper View: " + upperView);

            Animation anim = new ExpandCollapseUpperViewAnimation(upperViewsList.get(position), ExpandCollapseUpperViewAnimation.COLLAPSE);
            anim.setDuration(800);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                {
                    circleViewsList.get(position).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // upperViewsList.get(position).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    animateListExpand(button, target, position);
                }
            });
            upperViewsList.get(position).startAnimation(anim);

            // Lower animation

            Animation lowerAnim = new ExpandCollapseUpperViewAnimation(lowerViewsList.get(position), ExpandCollapseUpperViewAnimation.COLLAPSE);
            lowerAnim.setDuration(800);
            lowerViewsList.get(position).startAnimation(lowerAnim);
        }
    });
}

private void updateExpandable(View target, int position)
{

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) target.getLayoutParams();
    if (openItems.get(position))
    {
        target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        params.bottomMargin = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        target.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        params.bottomMargin = 0 - viewHeights.get(position);
    }
}

/**
 * Performs either COLLAPSE or EXPAND animation on the target view
 * 
 * @param target
 *            the view to animate
 * @param type
 *            the animation type, either ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE or ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND
 */
private void animateView(final View target, final int type)
{
    Animation anim = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(target, type);
    anim.setDuration(getAnimationDuration());
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            System.out.println("Animation End");
            if (type == ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND)
            {
                if (parent instanceof ListView)
                {
                    ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
                    int movement = target.getBottom();

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    boolean visible = target.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
                    Rect r2 = new Rect();
                    listView.getGlobalVisibleRect(r2);

                    if (!visible)
                    {
                        listView.smoothScrollBy(movement, getAnimationDuration());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (r2.bottom == r.bottom)
                        {
                            listView.smoothScrollBy(movement, getAnimationDuration());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
    target.startAnimation(anim);
}

private void animateWithUpperView(final View target, final int type, final int position)
{
    Animation anim = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(target, type);
    anim.setDuration(getAnimationDuration());
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            // upperViewsList.get(lastOpenItemForUpperView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // lastOpenItemForUpperView = position;
            Animation expandItemAniamtion = new ExpandCollapseLowerViewAnimation(upperViewsList.get(lastOpenItemIndex), ExpandCollapseUpperViewAnimation.EXPAND);
            expandItemAniamtion.setDuration(800);
            expandItemAniamtion.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                {
                    circleViewsList.get(lastOpenItemIndex).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lastOpenItemIndex = position;
                }
            });

            // Lower view animation
            Animation lowerAnim = new ExpandCollapseLowerViewAnimation(lowerViewsList.get(lastOpenItemIndex), ExpandCollapseUpperViewAnimation.EXPAND);
            lowerAnim.setDuration(800);

            upperViewsList.get(lastOpenItemIndex).startAnimation(expandItemAniamtion);

            lowerViewsList.get(lastOpenItemIndex).startAnimation(lowerAnim);
        }
    });
    target.startAnimation(anim);
}

/**
 * Closes the current open item. If it is current visible it will be closed with an animation.
 * 
 * @return true if an item was closed, false otherwise
 */
public boolean collapseLastOpen()
{
    if (isAnyItemExpanded())
    {
        // if visible animate it out
        if (lastOpen != null)
        {
            animateView(lastOpen, ExpandCollapseAnimation.COLLAPSE);
        }
        openItems.set(lastOpenPosition, false);
        lastOpenPosition = -1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState(Parcelable parcelable)
{

    SavedState ss = new SavedState(parcelable);
    ss.lastOpenPosition = this.lastOpenPosition;
    ss.openItems = this.openItems;
    return ss;
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(SavedState state)
{

    if (state != null)
    {
        this.lastOpenPosition = state.lastOpenPosition;
        this.openItems = state.openItems;
    }
}

/**
 * Utility methods to read and write a bitset from and to a Parcel
 */
private static BitSet readBitSet(Parcel src)
{
    BitSet set = new BitSet();
    if (src == null)
    {
        return set;
    }
    int cardinality = src.readInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < cardinality; i++)
    {
        set.set(src.readInt());
    }

    return set;
}

private static void writeBitSet(Parcel dest, BitSet set)
{
    int nextSetBit = -1;

    if (dest == null || set == null)
    {
        return; // at least dont crash
    }

    dest.writeInt(set.cardinality());

    while ((nextSetBit = set.nextSetBit(nextSetBit + 1)) != -1)
    {
        dest.writeInt(nextSetBit);
    }
}

/**
 * The actual state class
 */
static class SavedState extends View.BaseSavedState
{
    public BitSet openItems = null;
    public int lastOpenPosition = -1;

    SavedState(Parcelable superState)
    {
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in)
    {
        super(in);
        lastOpenPosition = in.readInt();
        openItems = readBitSet(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeInt(lastOpenPosition);
        writeBitSet(out, openItems);
    }

    // required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
    {
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new SavedState(in);
        }

        public SavedState[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}

public static Animation ExpandOrCollapseView(final View v, final boolean expand)
{
    try
    {
        Method m = v.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("onMeasure", int.class, int.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(v, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) v.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (expand)
    {
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight;
    }
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
        {
            int newHeight = 0;
            if (expand)
            {
                newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
            }
            else
            {
                newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
            }
            v.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            v.requestLayout();

            if (interpolatedTime == 1 && !expand)
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds()
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(1000);
    return a;
}}
```

Comment: I haven't gone through your code but, may be you are using such methods that arent supported in lower versions of android. Or if you think, the code you have written is all right, and still not working, then you can report issue to the developer of this library. He might help you more with this.

Comment: @ChintanSoni There are about 4 animations in a row. in KitKat and above all the animation runs, but below kitkat only 3 animations runs but does not run the 4th and last animation. If the issue is in animation then first 3 animation does not to be tun. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Luckily I have found the solution. On pre-kitkat the upperView on list item which was gone does not forcelly animate but on kitkat and so on it forcelly animate from gone to visible.
So as the solution we must give a layer of view between of list item and upper view (Which we have to animate).
In this way it will work like charm.